# Unity3d Raycast hit distance distortion

Tags: unity-game-engine, sensors, ros, raycasting, distortion

Im making a Laser sensor for a simulator in Unity3d; what I need to do is to cast rays from a point at different angles and then get the distances from another software outside Unity.
[image]
On the left the unity scene where the red lines are the casted rays, on the right the ray visualized on the other program. The program only recives the distances and the angles from the central point.
As you can see the points reproduced on the program are distorted.

This is the unity code i used to get the distances:

```
RaycastHit hit;

float max_dst = 20.0f*5;
int steps = 1080;
Vector3 raydir = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 135.0f,0.0f)*transform.forward;
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, -270.0f/steps,0.0f);

Vector3 startPos = transform.position + offset;

for(int i=0; i<steps; i++) {

    if (Physics.Raycast (startPos, raydir, out hit, max_dst))
        dists[i] = hit.distance;

    raydir = rot*raydir;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion for eliminate the distortion?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried tuning the max distance parameter?
Could this be due to floating point accumulation / precision problems with the angle (multiplications/divisions stacking up) or with the other program/sensor?
is the offset variable correct?

Comment: changing the max distance doesn't help; i dont think is a floating point accumulation because i have the same distortion at the begin of the scan; the offset its just a constant vector for setting the height, if i don't use it i have the same problem.

Comment: the other program is not mine and with a real sensor works well.